# Navigation bar: Tab icons disapear when I click on them

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on this navigation bar. I got the navigation bar to change to a different color whenever I click on tab, but that resulted to a problem: When I click on an icon, the bar changes colors but the tab's logo disappear. It reappears only when I click on another tab, which also disappears... in other words tabs disappear when clicked on and active. I couldn't find how that happens, I am new to this so any cue would be much appreciated if someone has time to spare.

Much thanks

HTML:

```
<!--Header-->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.0/css/all.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!--End Header-->

</head>

<body>

<!--Header-->
<div class="tab-nav-container">

    <div class="tab active purple">
        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="tab pink">
      <i class="far fa-code"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="tab teal">
        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="tab yellow">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="tab yellow">
        <i class="far fa-at"></i>
    </div>

</div>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
<!--End Header-->
```

CSS:

```
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: background 0.4s linear;

    text-align: center;

}

.tab-nav-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 500px;
}

.tab {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin: 0 0px;
    transition: tab-nav-container 0.4s linear;
}

.tab i {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.tab p {
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 0;
}

.tab.active p {
    margin-left: 0px;
    max-width: 300px;
    transition: max-width 0.1s linear;
}

.tab.active.purple {
    background-color: rgba(91, 55, 183, 0.2);
    color: rgba(91, 55, 183, 1);
}

.tab.active.pink {
    background-color: rgba(201, 55, 157, 0.2);
    color: rgba(201, 55, 157, 1);
}

.tab.active.yellow {
    background-color: rgba(230, 169, 25, 0.2);
    color: rgba(230, 169, 25, 1);
}

.tab.active.teal {
    background-color: rgba(28, 150, 162, 0.2);
    color: rgba(28, 150, 162, 1);
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
    .tab-nav-container {
        padding: 20px;
        width: 350px;
    }

    .tab {
        padding: 0 10px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .tab i {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

tabs.forEach(clickedTab => {
    // Add onClick event listener on each tab
    clickedTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Remove the active class from all the tabs (this acts as a "hard" reset)
          tabs.forEach(tab => {
            tab.classList.remove('active');
        });

        // Add the active class on the clicked tab
        clickedTab.classList.add('active');
        const clickedTabBGColor = getComputedStyle(clickedTab).getPropertyValue('color');
        console.log(clickedTabBGColor);
        banner.style.backgroundColor = clickedTabBGColor;
    });
});
```

Comment: What would one expect when you set background-color and font color to exact same color with only variation in opacity? Perhaps your monitor's white balance is set to high? As an experiment, set one of the tabs active `color`s to `black`.

Comment: Your links are divs! They should be a href tags to make the user go to somewhere on your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change some of the CSS properties and I think it's work fine with me:

[image]

edit: make sure FontAwesome classes are correct, I've used some other icons.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition:  0.4s linear;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-nav-container {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 500px;
}

.tab {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;  
  transition: tab-nav-container 0.4s linear;
}

.tab i {
  font-size: 2.2em;
}

.tab p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tab.active p {
  transition: max-width 0.1s linear;
}

.tab.active.purple {
  background-color: rgba(91, 55, 183, 0.2);
  color: rgba(91, 55, 183, 1);
}

.tab.active.pink {
  background-color: rgba(201, 55, 157, 0.2);
  color: rgba(201, 55, 157, 1);
}

.tab.active.yellow {
  background-color: rgba(230, 169, 25, 0.2);
  color: rgba(230, 169, 25, 1);
}

.tab.active.teal {
  background-color: rgba(28, 150, 162, 0.2);
  color: rgba(28, 150, 162, 1);
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .tab-nav-container {
      padding: 20px;
      width: 350px;
  }

  .tab {
      padding: 0 10px;
      margin: 0;
  }

  .tab i {
      font-size: 1em;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I got the cues I need it to fix it.
@Randy Casburn as my experience is limited, I don't always see those little things as clearly.
@pawnonfire Yes I know I was starting with the layout.
@EshgheCode Thanks a lot

Comment: It's good that you figured it out but this is not an answer to your question. Either accept an answer that someone else tried to help you with or post the solution you figured out. See https://xkcd.com/979/ for the problem we're trying to avoid.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know what it meant I'm new around here. Thanks